# How to use the default/unthemed Gnome?

Tags: gnome, themes

Sometimes I get the error that seems to be described in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1575703) (see [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10232537&postcount=23) for an image). However, despite it being an error, I actually enjoy the theme (or lack thereof) with it's carved buttons, no rounded corners and clear boundaries between elements. Maybe it just feels nostalgic, but anyway -- I want to know how to keep that theme (non-theme?) permanently.

Btw, it doesn't seem to be the Clearlooks theme, which according to what I read is the default Gnome theme, so I'm inclined to believe that it is Gnome unthemed.

Answer (score 1):

1) Open the file "%gconf.xml" at "~/.gconf/apps/metacity/general" (`gedit ~/.gconf/apps/metacity/general/%gconf.xml`)

2) Search for

`<entry name="theme" mtime="1335845353" type="string">

        <stringvalue>Radiance</stringvalue>`

3) Change "Radiance" for a non existing theme like "nonexistingtheme",

4) Save,

5) Logout and log back in.

6) Enjoy  ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, that only seems to work for window decorations. The Nautilus theme, interface buttons, menus, etc, all continue as they were before.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](http://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/06/13/a-new-default-theme-for-gtk/), I am inclined to believe that the "unthemed" interface was actually the [Raleigh theme](https://www.google.com/images?q=raleigh+theme).

I can't confirm that's true because the image linked to in the question has been removed from tinypic, so if someone knows better (any GTK whizzes around?), please comment below :)